# How to send a Gmail message using Advanced Gmail Service in GAS?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api

My objective is to retrieve the existing inbox message using the Gmail Advanced Service in GAS, modify the subject line and then call Gmail.Users.Messages.insert() to paste the new message to the inbox. 
I know I can achieve this result by uploading to Gmail API endpoints, but I'm trying to understand how the Advanced Service works and make the code less verbose.

According to the documentation, the "insert()" method accepts the message resource as the encoded string. The format is the following

```
Gmail.Users.Messages.insert({"raw":Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe(message)}, "me");
```

The 'message' parameter that is passed to the encoding function is supposed to be a Byte array representing the content of the message. I can get the bytes for the existing inbox message by inspecting its "raw" property.

```
var message = Gmail.Users.Messages.get("me", messageId, {format:"raw"});
var bytes = message.raw;
```

The problem is when you pass the {format: "raw"} as an optional parameter to the 'get()' method, you can no longer examine the properties of the message and access the 'payload' property. If you pass {format:"full"} instead, the payload is there, but not the "raw" property.

You can construct the new message using Gmail.newMessage() and set the properties manually but I have no clue how to use it with the "insert()" and "get()" methods. The return type for the 'newMessage()' method is 'Message' but there doesn't seem to be a single method in the Advanced Gmail Service that can accept parameters of this type. I'll still need to get the bytes for the message and encode them. However,

```
var message = Gmail.newMessage();
(Logger.log(message.raw));  // logs  undefined
```

Maybe I'm missing something but it looks like a massive catch-22. I don't understand why the message builder Gmail.newMessage() method is even there if you can't use it easily with other methods that are supposed to be wrappers around Gmail API.

Answer (score 3):

Methods prefixed with `new` in an Advanced Service serve to generate empty ***resource*** objects. They exist solely for the purpose of code completion in the Apps Script editor. To use them effectively you have to set the required properties on the objects produced by these methods and then pass them to methods that require that resource.

So in your case you'd create a message as follows:

```
var messageResource = Gmail.newMessage();

messageResource.raw = Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe([messageData]);
```

Then you'd pass it to the insert method:

```
Gmail.Users.Messages.insert(messageResource, "me");
```

They may seem redundant but some may find the code completion on these resource objects valuable.

Personally, I tend to avoid using them and just pass in objects as needed (just as you have in your initial example). Once you know the requisite properties on those resource objects you can drop those "training wheels" and just use in-line objects instead.

As for this issue:

> The problem is when you pass the {format: "raw"} as an optional parameter to the 'get()' method, you can no longer examine the properties of the message and access the 'payload' property. If you pass {format:"full"} instead, the payload is there, but not the "raw" property.

Its an either or situation with the `Gmail.Users.Messages.get()` method. If you look at the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get) you'll see that you have to set the format parameter and thus you can't get all the information you need in one call. However all you have to do is make two calls; one where format is set to **"full"** and another where format is set to **"raw"** and then you'll have what you need. The code may not be the most elegant but it will achieve your goals.

---

To address the issue stated in your comment; I suspect you might need to leverage [media uploads](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/uploads#simple). The insert method has multiple signatures as seen in the screenshot below:
[image]
You'll probably need to leverage either the 2nd or 3rd options to upload the message data. Edit the payload object and change the subject line and pass that in your message resource and then convert the raw data to a blob `Utilities.newBlob([raw Byte[]])` (you'll need to convert the raw base64-encoded string to a byte array before converting it to a Blob object) and pass that in as the 3rd parameter. Not sure if that will work but its worth a shot.

Comment: Thanks, the documentation was extremely confusing on this. What I'd like to do, however, is to copy the existing message and insert it into the inbox with the new subject line.  I can only directly inspect the message properties by passing {format:"full"} to the 'get()' request. In this case, the raw property is not accessible. Similarly, if I only get the 'raw' property, how do I parse it to get the subject line? Not sure how you get the "messageText" variable in your example. Am I supposed to manually build RFC 2822 MIME message? This sounds like a lot of work and there no libraries.

Comment: Basically, my objective is to copy the original inbox message, change the subject line, paste the new message into the exact same location and finally, delete the original one (since messages are immutable and can't be edited)

Comment: I understand that you can make 2 calls, but setting the 'raw' property of the new message is what confuses me. Even if I build the new message resource with the new subject line and copy all other properties from the original message, the 'raw' property will still be undefined. If I set it to the value of 'raw' of the original message, the subject line change will not happen when I call "insert()" - it will simply insert the complete carbon copy of the message.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find the quick-and-dirty shortcut using Regex. Upvoting Dimu's solution as it's probably much better in the long run but I need to take a deeper dive.

```
var message = GmailApp.getMessageById(messageId);
var rawContent = message.getRawContent();
// Regex logic for matching the subject line
rawContent = rawContent.replace(oldSubjectLine, newSubjectLine);
var encodedMsg = Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe(rawContent);

var message = Gmail.newMessage();
message.raw = encodedMsg;

Gmail.Users.Messages.insert(message, "me");
```

Comment: This works perfectly. `getRawContent()` returns String while `Gmail.Users.Messages.get('me', id, {format: 'raw'}).raw` returns Byte Array. The former is much easier to use with Regex.

Answer (score 0):

Just to build on what's been co-created between the commenters here, I'll share the code I've created to successfully get a draft by its ID, modify the recipient, and send the message using the Advanced Gmail Service in GAS. This solution took me (literally) days to develop.

```js
function sendFromDraft (id, recipient) {
  // get the draft by ID and its raw content
  var message = GmailApp.getMessageById(id);
  var rawContent = message.getRawContent();
  
  // determines if recipient is already defined in draft, routes accordingly, updates with new recipient
  var addRecipient = 'To: <' + recipient + '>';
  var recipientFromTemplate = rawContent.match(/To:.[^>]+>/);
  if (recipientFromTemplate === null) {
    var fromField = rawContent.match(/From:.[^>]+>/);
    var updateWithRecipient = fromField + '\n' + addRecipient;
    rawContent = rawContent.replace(fromField, updateWithRecipient);    
  } else {
    rawContent = rawContent.replace(recipientFromTemplate, addRecipient);
  }
  
  var message = Gmail.newMessage();
  var encodedMsg = Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe(rawContent);

  message.raw = encodedMsg;
  
  Gmail.Users.Messages.send(message, "me", Utilities.newBlob(rawContent, "message/rfc822"));
};
```

I have to shout out [Romain Vialard](https://www.linkedin.com/in/romainvialard/) and the commenters above for adding critical information that enabled me to develop the working code. I hope this helps other devs in the future.